# Referenced object no longer exists?

Tags: vba, coreldraw

So I have a macro to search all texts on a document and convert them all to curves. This macro also would look through powerclip which is out of range of CQL.

Below is my code:

```
Public Sub convertText()
    Dim pg As Page
    Dim shRange As ShapeRange
    Dim sh As Shape

    For Each pg In ActiveDocument.Pages
        pg.Activate
        Set shRange = FindAllPCShapes.Shapes.FindShapes(Query:="@type='text:artistic' or @type='text:paragraph'")
        For Each sh In shRange
            sh.ConvertToCurves
        Next sh
    Next pg
End Sub

Function FindAllPCShapes(Optional LngLevel As Long) As ShapeRange ' Shelby's function
    Dim s As Shape
    Dim srPowerClipped As New ShapeRange, srJustClipped As New ShapeRange
    Dim sr As ShapeRange, srAll As New ShapeRange
    Dim bFound As Boolean, i&

    bFound = False
    If ActiveSelection.Shapes.count > 0 Then
        Set sr = ActiveSelection.Shapes.FindShapes()
    Else
        Set sr = ActivePage.Shapes.FindShapes()
    End If
    i = 0
    Do
        For Each s In sr.Shapes.FindShapes(Query:="!@com.powerclip.IsNull")
            srPowerClipped.AddRange s.PowerClip.Shapes.FindShapes()
        Next s
        If srPowerClipped.count > 0 Then bFound = True: i = i + 1
        If i = LngLevel And bFound Then Set FindAllPCShapes = srPowerClipped: Exit Function
        bFound = False
        srAll.AddRange sr
        sr.RemoveAll
        sr.AddRange srPowerClipped
        If LngLevel = -1 Then srJustClipped.AddRange srPowerClipped
        srPowerClipped.RemoveAll
    Loop Until sr.count = 0

    If LngLevel = -1 Then
        Set FindAllPCShapes = srJustClipped
    Else
        Set FindAllPCShapes = srAll
    End If
End Function
```

It works fine on some cases, but I caught an error on some document where For Each sh In shRange will generate an error "The Referenced Object no longer exists". Apparently this is because of a nested group inside a powerclip.

I tried to ignore the error by adding On Error Resume Next and the macro will runs fine. But of course I want to know what's the error with my code so I can avoid future troubles, I rather not to ignore all the errors on my macro.

Here's a sample document to demonstrate the error.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpi568eoltc8cxy/ReferenceError.cdr?dl=0

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error I think encountered is due to **Nothing** is returned by the FindShapes method.

Before the For loop, you should check if it's **Nothing**:

```
For Each pg In ActiveDocument.Pages
    pg.Activate
    Set shRange = FindAllPCShapes.Shapes.FindShapes(Query:="@type='text:artistic' or @type='text:paragraph'")
    If Not shRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each sh In shRange
            sh.ConvertToCurves
        Next sh
    End If
Next pg
```

Comment: Nope that still doesn't do anything, the error occurs inside the ForEach loop so it will never check shRange is Nothing anymore once it's inside the loop.

Comment: Don't have CorelDraw to test your file, based on the syntax it may be `For Each sh In shRange.Shapes`?